# Proper Binding of a TextBox to an Object Property

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, textbox, inotifypropertychanged

I have a class with a property that I need to bind to a form TextBox in VB.NET. So far none of my attempts will have the TextBox updating in real time from the object properties.

I have the following code in my class

```
Public Class Servo

    Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private _ServoID As Integer

    Property ServoID() As Integer

        Get
            Return _ServoID
        End Get

        Set(ByVal Value As Integer)

            _ServoID = Value
            Call LoadModelInfo()

            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("ServoID"))

        End Set

    End Property


End Class
```

On the form load event I have the binding code

```
TextBoxCurrServoID.DataBindings.Add("Text", CurrentServoFormServoManager, "ServoID", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
```

The object from the class is declared in module for global variables

```
Public CurrentServoFormServoManager As RobotModel2.Servo = New RobotModel2.Servo
```

The object/class works fine, I can write and read data from it's properties, no problems. If I attach/create a BindingList with it and set that as the datasource to a DataGridView the cells in the DataGridView update properly. I just can't seem to get it working with a TextBox. I can't see what I might be missing. Thanks.

EDIT - MORE INFORMATION:

After further research I found a similar post which mentioned that binding to a property of a class while the property is null can cause it not to work. You have to have data there BEFORE binding.

I added a button on the form and moved the binding code there and commented it out on the load event. I then load the form. Populate the CurrentServoFormServoManager object with data, then click the button to bind the TextBoxes to CurrentServoFormServoManager properties. And that works. I can programmatically change the data and the TextBoxes update.

The problem is. I cannot really use this as a solution. The object CurrentServoFormServoManager is constantly being destroyed and remade in this program. As soon as you make it = nothing or = to a new servo object the databinding breaks and has to be reset. I cannot do this since that event is happening outside of the form control. It is triggered by packets coming in from the serial port at different times. IE: I have to hang the form in order to wait for the serial packet to then rebind the data. And that is the solution I'm trying to get away from in the code.

I also attempted to populate the servo object, then bind the TextBoxes, and then only update the data without rebuilding the object and that can be updated from buttons on the form, but incoming threadsafe data from a serial packet will not update the TextBoxes. The data is properly updating in the object properties, and the datagrid which is bound through a BindingList updates fine, but the TextBoxes won't.

So... I'm still without a solution on how to bind TextBoxes to the properties of a class object that can be preset and left in place.

Comment: what the heck is `CurrentServoFormServoManager`?

Comment: What UI framework are you using?

Comment: I am in vb.net building on a windows form.   CurrentServoFormServoManager is just an instance of the Servo class. Lol. I use long names when I'm trying different things out during R&D.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code.  You may have inadvertently obscured `TextBoxCurrServoID` in the designer with another textbox.  Try adding `TextBoxCurrServoID.BringToFront()` to your Form_Load handler code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly not the best solution, but if you are creating and destroying `Servo` objects (i.e. constantly changing the `CurrentServoFormServoManager` reference), then perhaps you need a container class that holds the `Servo` reference and exposes its properties by delegation, then raise an event when either the reference or the property changes.

e.g. container class:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class ServoContainer
  Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged

  Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

  Private WithEvents _servo As Servo

  Sub New()
    _servo = New Servo
  End Sub

  Property Servo As Servo
    Get
      Return _servo
    End Get
    Set(value As Servo)
      _servo = value
      RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("ServoID"))
    End Set
  End Property

  Private Sub _servo_PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Handles _servo.PropertyChanged
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("ServoID"))
  End Sub

  Property ServoID As Integer
    Get
      Return _servo.ServoID
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
      _servo.ServoID = value
    End Set
  End Property
End Class
```

Instantiating the container:

```
Public CurrentServoContainer As ServoContainer = New ServoContainer
```

Replace your current textbox binding as follows:

```
TextBoxCurrServoID.DataBindings.Add("Text", CurrentServoContainer, "ServoID", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
```

Now, both of the following lines will update the textbox:

```
CurrentServoContainer.Servo.ServoID = 99
```

and

```
CurrentServoContainer.Servo = New Servo With {.ServoID = 98} 'replace with your actual constructor'
```

Comment: It may not be the best solution as you say, but thank you for suggesting it because it works. Containers are new to me so I've also learned about a new tool. It appears that visual Basic or the form does not like it trying to be updated from the thread being created by the incoming serial packet. A BindingList gets around that for when you are using a collection of objects and a GridView, but in many cases that doesn't work. Like in this scenario. Somehow, adding the container layer makes the form happy and it updates. Thank you.

Comment: I think what's happening in your original code is that when you bind the first time, it is binding to the actual object, not the variable name. So when you change the object that the variable name is pointing to, the binding still sticks with the original object, not the new one.

Comment: That would make sense, but for right now, I'm not changing the object. I set up code where the object is created at run time and all I do is update the data in the properties. When I do it through code from a button it works. When I do it through a threadsafe function called from an inbound serial packet the TextBoxes simply won't update. But they do with your container solution.

Comment: Oh well, as long as it works, right? :-) Glad I could help.

Comment: Exactly, lol. Thank you very much! Got me out of a nasty bug!